# Can i Get data more than one div using cURL

Tags: php, curl, preg-match-all

I have a problem, I want to get data from another website and display it on my website using cURL.

For example, this is data from the other website which I would like to parse and display on my website.

```
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 1</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 2</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 3</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 4</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 5</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 6</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 7</a></div>
<div class="users-name"> <a href='#'>User 8</a></div>

<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 1 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 2 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 3 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 4 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 5 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 6 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 7 Address</a></div>
<div class="users-name-address"><a href='#'>User 8 Address</a></div>
```

Currently I'm getting all user names, but now I want to get all of this address along with User name so i will place correct address with correct user.

I have tried this so far:

```
$curl = curl_init('www.domain.com/search.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="users-name">(.*?)<\/div>/s';

if(preg_match_all($regex, $page, $list))
    print_r($list[0]);
else
    print "Not found";
```

Comment: Stop Reposting the same question

Comment: Its not same problem sir

Comment: cURL is New for me. I'm using First time @EmilyShepherd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do that without regex:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$queryName = '//div[@class = "users-name"]/a';
$queryAddress = '//div[@class = "users-name-address"]/a';

function getTextFromNodes($nodeList) {
    $textArray = array();
    foreach($nodeList as $listItem) {
        $textArray[] = $listItem->textContent; 
    }
    return $textArray;
}

$names = getTextFromNodes($xpath->query($queryName));
$addresses = getTextFromNodes($xpath->query($queryAddress));

$result = array_combine($names, $addresses);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: its return empty array like this Array ( )

Comment: @user3487256: I have tested it with your example string (I have set `$page` with it) and it works well, try `print_r($names);` and `print_r($addresses);`